# Upgrating from 12.10 to 14.10 failed

Tags: upgrade, software-center, package-management, update-manager

I got this error while upgrading from 12.10 to 14.10:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted
```

What should I do?

Comment: Which 12.x release were you on?

Comment: It is the 12.10 one.

Comment: 12.10 and the variants between 12.04 and 14.04 are all End of Life.  I'd suggest you start here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but it didn't work.

Comment: What's the new error message then? If it's the same, you (very likely) didn't do it right.

Comment: You can't upgrade directly to 14.10 from 12.10.

Answer (score 2):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In the open file.

Delete the contents.

Paste the following:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu utopic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu utopic partner
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-proposed universe multiverse restricted main
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Continue running:

```
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
UNUSCONF=$(dpkg -l|grep "^rc"|awk '{print $2}')
apt-get remove --purge $UNUSCONF
NEWKERNEL=$(uname -r|sed 's/-*[a-z]//g'|sed 's/-386//g')
ADDKERNEL="linux-(image|headers|ubuntu-modules|restricted-modules)"
METAKERNEL="linux-(image|headers|restricted-modules)-(generic|i386|server|common|rt|xen)"
UNUSKERNELS=$(dpkg -l|awk '{print $2}'|grep -E $ADDKERNEL |grep -vE $METAKERNEL|grep -v $NEWKERNEL)
apt-get remove --purge $UNUSKERNELS
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get clean
reboot
```